# Connecting a Windows Application to online database[Vb.Net]

Tags: windows, vb.net, web

Question 1 :

Hi, I'm new to "VB.Net" and programming. Me and my friend is developing a Windows Application in VB.NET and we wanted to connect to a online MySql database. We already did it in the same pc[localhost]. But we wanted to know wether is it possible to connect a online MySql database to Vb.net Windows Application (not a web application)?

Question 2:

What is the name used to call Windows Applications that are connected to a online server?

Some examples I know are Steam application and Facebook Messenger.
[Where you can download the application, install and log in to the server.]

Comment: 1. Yes, it's possible, you just a running database and a connection string.
2. A client

Comment: 1.You can find connection strings from www.connectionstrings.com.  2. Your 2nd question is not clear

Comment: RE Q2 AFAIK there is no term that means precisely this. "Client/Server" is often taken to mean the server is in the server room next door, although this term does include what you're doing. "Web-enabled" is another I've seen used. 
Also, while it's certainly possible to access a db in this way, be aware that your database will be the target of every casual snooper with a port scanner. And there's a lot of them.